# Chrome Extension error message: Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated and Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, port, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How is the linked previous question and answer is related to my question? the error message is not even the same... please reopen my question

I am working on a personal project for my programing course and I have tried to create a basic chrome extension that allows me to add a word and the meaning of the word in a pop-up and save it. After saving the given word the extension should display the meaning of the word as a tooltip when I highlight that particular word in my chrome browser.
I am getting the following error messages:

Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated and
Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object

and the error messages highlights the following part of the codes:

port.postMessage({ action: "highlight", text: selectedText });

First i didnt get any error messages when i installed. but after i tested and added a few words and their meanings the error messages appeared.

I have checked other posts / questions regarding this issue but it didnt help.

I also tried troubleshooting with the help of chatgpt but it couldnt solve this issue. Chatgpt tried to provide me with different approaches but none of them worked and i was getting the very same error messages.

Your help and suggestions would be highly appreciated!